# Is this a bug in Vim's string expression evaluation?

Tags: vim

I was debugging a problem with a plugin running in Vim73 on Arch Linux and it seems to stem from an error in string expression evaluation.

In this Vim installation the expression `'xxx' > ''` evaluates to 0 (false) while in all other Vims I've seen the expression evaluates (as it should) to 1 (true).

Does anyone know the explanation for this? The Arch Linux Vim was not compiled with lots of features built in, but could there really be some feature that changes the evaluation of string expressions?

Is there some Vim setting (encoding?) that might have changed the result of this string comparison?  It was a plain-jane install of Vim (nothing of note in vimrc) giving the bad result, didn't see anwhere a setting could have been changed even if there is some setting that affects this result.

Thanks for any info.

**UPDATE:**
It turns out this problem was caused by a bug in the string comparison function in recent version of 64-bit Vim when the Vim flag 'ignorecase' is set.  A non-empty string should be greater than an empty string regardless of whether case is ignored, but Vim was returning false.  Bug report is here:
http://groups.google.com/group/vim_dev/browse_thread/thread/313bc7c46a19cd40

Workarounds would be: (1) use comparison operator that forces 'matchcase' comparison, e.g., `mystring_var ># ''`  or (2) use `!empty(mystring_var)` .

Comment: Can you show the actual code where the expression is used?

Comment: You can ask the user to try loading vim with other ftplugin (triggering it the same way) to see if it is your plugin's problem or vim itself.

Answer (score 1):

To know the answer for this question you have to take a look at the documentation. Here is a quote of the [`*41.4* Conditionals`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_41.html#41.4) section:

> The logic operators work both for numbers and strings.  When comparing two
>   strings, the mathematical difference is used.  This compares byte values,
>   which may not be right for some languages.
>
> When comparing a string with a number, the string is first converted to a
>   number.  This is a bit tricky, because when a string doesn't look like a
>   number, the number zero is used.  Example:
>
> ```
> :if 0 == "one"
> :  echo "yes"
> :endif
> ```
>
> This will echo "yes", because "one" doesn't look like a number, thus it is
>   converted to the number zero.

Apparently, vim does not guarantee the result for the operation you are trying to perform and you shouldn't rely on it. If you want to compare the length of the strings, take a look at [`*strlen()*`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#strlen%28%29).

Comment: @freitass -- Thanks, but I don't see how that answers my problem. First, I'm comparing two strings, not a string and a number.  Second, in comparing a nonempty string against an empty string, is there any time that 'nonemptystring' > '' should evaluate to 0?  Third, the vim install returns different results for the same expression after my ftplugin is initialized. (See UPDATE in question above.) Am I still missing something here?

Comment: Based on vim docs, it doesn't support your expression and it doesn't mean that vim will stop working when receiving such expression, it can just return some random answer. Unless you point me where does vim doc says what "string < string" does, I can't rely on the '<' operator for strings. The answer is: use `*strlen()*`. Btw, I still don't know what you want to compare (is it the string length?).

Comment: @freitass: I think you're misunderstanding what the documentation says.  It doesn't say you can't compare strings, or that results of string comparison might be random.  That is ridiculous.  It says the results "may not be right for some languages".  That was why I asked about encodings in my question.  But even with same encoding the two machines return different values for the same expression.  I don't see how that can be right.

Comment: Sorry, I have indeed misunderstood it. And seeing your update there is no much I can do since I don't run ArchLinux.

Comment: On vim's message group someone has I think correctly identified the problem as related to use of the setting 'ignorecase'.  When ignorecase is set some vim installs return a value of false for this expression: `'anystring' > ''` .  I think this must be related to a flaw in either the design or implementation of 'ignorecase' but still trying to figure things out.  (wondering now whether it happens only on 64-bit vim. . .)

Comment: For the record: when you compare in your code `'anystring' > ''`, you want to know if `'anystring'` is not empty?

Comment: @freitass:  Yes.  Same thing can be done with !empty(stringvar) but so far as I know the comparison is also common method in many languages.  Also, comparison to empty string could happen many times when right-hand side is string variable with unknown value.  These '>', '<' string comparisons are frequently used, e.g, when sorting a list of strings to order them alphabetically.  (BTW, the problem has been confirmed to result from a bug in 64-bit versions of Vim, as updated in question.)